# Data Entry Beginner Asks: How do I 'section' out rows of a spreadsheet to belong to a product/item/object?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, iwork-numbers

I am a complete beginner to data entry and wanted to know how to accomplish the following with the sample dataset provided below.

[image: Sample Dataset (Apples, Oranges, Bananas)]

- Search through quantity column for "equal to or greater than value of 20"
- If value exists before hitting the next object 'apples, oranges, bananas' then print value on a new column on the same line as the object.
- If value does not exist print the last value it found for that object on a new column on the same line as the object.

I know the dataset is laid out a little weird, and would be much simpler to have the various quantities on the same row as the object it co-relates to, but unfortunately that is not the case for me..

Any help or guidance to get thinking on the right path would be great!

Currently, I am unsure of how to even begin to approach this problem..

Comment: I'd change the heading. This isn't data entry. Data entry is just entering data.

Comment: A little more feedback.  The task isn't clear.  It seems you want to always use the last value for each item.  The presence or absence of a quantity >=20 appears irrelevant.  Can there be more than one value >=20?  If so, what value do you use (all >=20, highest)?  What value do you want to post in a new column (the selected quantity, associated price)?  Can we assume the quantity data is always sorted in ascending order?  It would be useful to show what the output should look like for this example.  Please specify what application you're using (you've specified 3 and one is off-topic).